# Google Map Current location icon Customization

Tags: android, google-maps

I can able to customize the current location icon with location client the only problem is left out is that the bearing is not correct . Am using the bearing returned by the location object but when i apply the bearing with my image it's pointing to different location compared to Google map application :(.  It would be really helpful if any one can provide me solution for finding out the right bearing value .

Is there any way to change the size of the default current location icon?

Comment: follow the below link for the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19651535/1923399

Answer (score 0):

Show some of your codes and the image of the result. I don't get what you want.
If you want to change the size of the icon here is the code.

`var url =`
`{
url: 'images/asdf.png';
size: new google.maps.Size(40,40)`
}

Comment: This question belongs to android platform

Comment: im not familiar in the syntax in android. try to put it in array