# How to change the color of myLocationButton in google map SDK in swift 2.3?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, swift2

How to change color programatically of mylocationbutton in google map SDK-Swift.

Comment: Your problem is already in [gmaps-api-issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7594&q=myLocationButton&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) and it seems like no one check/accept this enhacement. What can I suggest you is try the idea here in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon) to use your own icon as your myLocationButton.

Comment: @KENdi..thanks a lot for the suggestion