# How do you change the points of interest icons (places) in google maps using android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-places

Using Google's api, I understand how to change the style of a map but I can't figure out how to change the icon for a specific point of interest.

I want to change the icon for business using the JSON style:

```
{
\"featureType\": \"poi.business\",
\"elementType\": \"labels.icon\",
\"stylers\": [
  {
    \"visibility\": \"on\"
  }
]
```

}

but how do I set that icon to something else?

Comment: Maybe this link solve you problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon

Comment: Thanks, but that only affects "markers".  I could probably add a custom marker at those locations and just hide the poi icons, but I'm guessing there is a way to change the default poi icons