# How to change google map default Current Location Marker color

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I want to change the default current **location marker color** from **blue to other**. Any body help me out how to do that.

Below is the icon color which I want to change:

[image: image is here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Maps API v2 Change MyLocation Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon)

Comment: @Hanzala this is not duplicate .. I just want to change the default icon color to use different marker

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
YOU CAN'T CHANGE THE DEFAULT ONE, YOU HAVE TO MAKE YOU OWN AND HIDE THE DEFAULT

You can use your own markers by adding them to the map.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(currentLocationMarker.getPosition());
markerOptions.title(getString(R.string.start));
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mapPin));
originMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Additionally you can change the theme of the map using map style JSON files.

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getActivity(), R.raw.map_night_style));
```

You can easily create you own style with google at the following link:
[Style with google](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

And here is the full documentation on customizing your map:
[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling)

Comment: Mark first i don't want to add different marker i just want to change the color of the existing marker.

Second thing i have customize the map but i didn't get any prpoperty there to change my current default marker color..if you know the property  or method name please let me know

Comment: @DeepakRana did you find another way to implement this?

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren no

Comment: I ended up creating a custom marker :( without the radius