# Customizing the current location indicator pin of Xamarin.Forms Map

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to customize the current location indicator of the Xamarin.Forms map to display a custom icon that also denotes the directional bearing of the user's device but I cannot seem to figure out the way to alter the current location indicator on the Android platform.

On the iOS platform, the current indicator annotation can be altered by merely checking if the annotation in concern pertains to the user's location in the overridden implementation of the `GetViewForAnnotation()` method, which is evoked when the location of the concerned annotation becomes visible on the map, available in the `MapRenderer` class.

```
protected override MKAnnotationView
      GetViewForAnnotation
       (MKMapView mapView,
        IMKAnnotation annotation) {
   if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
     // Customize location marker
   }
   else {}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230749/8395242

Comment: You could check the MS docs about the customize map pin for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin