# current location marker on the kotlin, google maps

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, location

I am writing an app on Androd using Kotlin, my app has google maps, I found out that there is already a built-in rendering of the current location using

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
mMap = googleMap
mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}
```

My question is, is there any way to change the color of the current location marker or even put some kind of picture instead of this blue dot. I just really need to change the blue dot to my own picture and the beam that shows where the user is looking to correct somehow, because it just teleports and I want it to show smoothly as in other applications. If there is any articles or youtube videos would be grateful.

Comment: There's currently no feature to modify the built-in rendering of the current location, there's a similar question which says that you can only make custom markers on top: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230634/how-to-change-google-map-default-current-location-marker-color. But since this is not the documented way of doing it, you can file a [Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker) for this.