# How to Replace the Google Map Current Location Blue Icon with a Custom Icon in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my code for getting current location. If anyone knows a way of doing this, kindly help. I'm stuck.

```
    private fun enableMyLocation() {
        if (isPermissionGranted()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return
            }
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't replace the blue icon with your custom icon, instead you should make the blue icon invisible and create  your own custom marker then update the marker on location changed event listener.

Comment: please check this link [simmilar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/replace-default-android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon)

Comment: There is also an open feature request for this in Google's Public Issue Tracker. You can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/169729868